# Icinga2: how to configure to get value from the host configuration to monitoring load average per servers?

Tags: nagios, nrpe, icinga

How to configure to get value from the host configuration to monitoring load average per servers?

I would like to pass different LA values to different hosts. I use NRPE agent on a host. My current configuration is:

On the a server nrpe.conf

```
command[check_load]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_load -r -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$
```

on the Icinga server

```
    object CheckCommand "nrpe-load" {
    import "nrpe-common"
    vars.nrpe_args = [ "$load_wgreater$", "$load_cgreater$" ]
    vars.nrpe_command = "check_load"
    vars.load_wgreater = 2
    vars.load_cgreater = 5
}

apply Service "load-nrpe-linux" {
import "generic-service"
display_name = "load"
check_command = "nrpe-load"
assign where (host.vars.os == "Linux" || host.vars.os == "awslinux") && host.vars.is_nrpe
}

object Host "domain.be-PHP-FPM" {
import "generic-host"
...

    vars.nrpe_load["6"] = {
    load_cgreater = 0.01
    }
    vars.nrpe_load["12"] = {
    load_cgreater = 12
    }
...
```

Help me, please, how to properly pass values in the host sections? Servers has different number of cores by this reason needs to use different values.

P.S.
Currently used values from vars.load_wgreater = 2 vars.load_cgreater = 5.

Regards,
Rostyslav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
vars.nrpe_load["6"] = {
load_cgreater = 0.01
}
vars.nrpe_load["12"] = {
load_cgreater = 12
}
```

Try this in each host definition where you need different values for `load_wgreater` and `load_cgreater` :

```
vars.load_wgreater = <v1>
vars.load_cgreater = <v2>
```

You don't need to use dict to assign values to `load_wgreater` and `load_cgreater`.

Comment: Jijin P: Thank you! It is help me.